# rspec expect to receive caring about just one parameter a couple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I wanted to do the following within rspec: Test that a method get's called with a particular argument no matter what the others are.

For example I would like to test `MyClass.receive(:new).with(anything, anything, testedObject)`. Is this possible to do with rspec?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [see doc](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/message-expectations):

```
MyClass.should_receive(:new).with(anything, anything, your_object)
```

Comment: Sorry missed the anything method